# how to fix input type checkbox right side align and click hole label display remaining text?

Tags: html, css

I need to set input type checkbox right side align. I am trying this but the checkbox name can't move to right side.

```css
body {
  color: #fff; 
  background-color: #000;
}

.detail {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3.6em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: auto;
}

#more:checked + div {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <div class="detail">Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on a modified version of the Linux kernel and other open source software and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets. In addition, Google has further developed Android TV for televisions, Android Auto for cars, and Wear OS for wrist watches, each with a specialized user interface. Variants of Android are also used on game consoles, digital cameras, PCs and other electronics.</div>
  <input id="more" type="checkbox" style="display: none">...Read more
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
body {color: #fff; background: #000}

.detail {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3.6em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: justify;
}

#more {display: none}

#more:checked + label > .detail {height: auto}

label {pointer-events: none} /* optional */

.read {
  pointer-events: initial; /* optional */
  text-align: right;
  background: #777; /* "block" demo */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.read:after {content: "...Read more"}

#more:checked + label > .read:after {content: "...Read less"}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <input id="more" type="checkbox">
  <label for="more">
    <div class="detail">Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on a modified version of the Linux kernel and other open source software and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets. In addition, Google has further developed Android TV for televisions, Android Auto for cars, and Wear OS for wrist watches, each with a specialized user interface. Variants of Android are also used on game consoles, digital cameras, PCs and other electronics.</div>
    <div class="read"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```